# Java - iterating through an ArrayList; display next or previous item based on user Input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to iterate  through an ArrayList, displaying the elements step by step, either the next element or the previous one depending on the users input. Here is my example code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProbaCuLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();

        animals.add("fox");
        animals.add("cat");
        animals.add("dog");
        animals.add("rabbit");

        for (String animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = input2.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {
            if (test == 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.println(animals.get(j));
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

currently, it outputs the elements corectly in the for-each loop, but the next bit of code it outputs me: fox, fox, fox, dog.
I want after the user writes 2 to print the first element and after that it the user presses 2 again it prints the next element and so on untill the end of the list.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it to see what's going wrong ?

Comment: You obviously check for user input only once. You don't have any code in the second loop that will check if user pressed 2 again.

Comment: try `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int index = 0;
do {
 int test = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
 if (test == 2) {
  System.out.println(animals.get(index++));
 }
} while (index < animals.size());
System.out.println("Thank you!");
scan.close();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of I have realized correctly this task, you have a list of animals and want to output one elements step by step every time while user press `2`:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < animals.size()) {
        if (scan.nextInt() == 2)
            System.out.println(animals.get(i++));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is not doing what you want. I commented the lines to show you what it does :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) { //for each animal
        if (test == 2) { //check if test equals 2
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //for each animal until the selected one from the first loop
                System.out.println(animals.get(j));  //print is name
                j++; //increase j
            }
        }
    }
```

First why do you wheck test everytime ? it's value won't change during the loop, you could check it first and only one time.

Your first loop go through all the animals.

The second loop goes through the animal from the beginning until the animal selected from the first loop. Then is display it names. In this loop you increase j, but it's already done in the declaration of the loop. So you increase j too often.

---

To show you what happens : First i = 0. Then j = 0, So j is not lower than i the loop stop. Second i=1, then j=0 so you print "fox". Then you increase j and the loop increase j -> j=2. So j is not lower than i the loop stop. Third i=2, j=0 so you print "fox". Then you increase j and the loop increase j -> j=2. So j is not lower than i the loop stop. Fourth i=3, j=0 so you print "fox". Then you increase j and the loop increase j -> j=2. j is lower than i so you do the loop again. you print "dog". Then you increase j and the loop increase j -> j=4. So j is not lower than i the loop stop. the loop through i stops.

---

I supposed the "code" for the user inputs are 0 -> exit, 1->prev, 2->next.

```
public class ProbaCuLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userInput = 2;
        int index = 0;

        animals.add("fox");
        animals.add("cat");
        animals.add("dog");
        animals.add("rabbit");

        for (String animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }

        while(userInput != 0) {
            userInput = scan.nextInt();

            if(userInput == 2) {
                System.out.println(animals.get(index);
                if(index<animals.size()) {
                    index++;
                 }
            }
            if(userInput == 1) {
                System.out.println(animals.get(index);
                if(index>1) {
                    index--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : this is one solution, but there's a lot, and surely some better

Answer (score 0):

I think below fulfill your requirement.

import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ProbaCuLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();

        animals.add("fox");
        animals.add("cat");
        animals.add("dog");
        animals.add("rabbit");

        for (String animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test;
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter the Key");
            test = input2.nextInt();
            if(test==2 && i<animals.size()){
                System.out.println(animals.get(i));
                i++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Out of the Loop");
                break;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` my eyes are hurting. Appart from the joke, just put the condition of your `else{break;}` as the condition of the loop. Always avoid using `while(true)`